# UITableView cell separator is cutting when rotate to Landscape in iPad

Tags: uitableview, ios7

when i rotate my iPad to `Landscape` mode , the `UITableViewCell's` separator is cutting at half and not reach to the end like following pic.

I have already make autoresizing to my `UITableView` too.

But it doesn't work when rotate to Landscape.

How can i do that?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to set the appropriate constraints to the `contentView`?

Comment: what do you mean bro?

Comment: Try this [self.tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/19390930/764822 and there is a solution:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle separatorStyle = self.tableView.separatorStyle;
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = separatorStyle;
}
```